# Replacing characters with specified one

Tags: sql, string, replace, character

I have a string as follows - MFMFMF

now i want to change this string to FMFMFM how to do this , help needed pls

i had tried

select replace(replace('mfmfmf','M','F'),'F','M') 
this gives me result - MMMMMM
which i donot what
i want the output to be FMFMFM
Need your help

D.Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select replace(replace(replace('mfmfmf', 'm', 'x'), 'f', 'm'), 'x', 'f') ...
```

It's because your first replace yields:

```
ffffff
```

And then replacing `f`s with `m`s, yields `mmmmmm`.  You need an intermediary replace.

Comment: I don't think he expects the strings to be the same each time.  Which means he'll eventually end up with a string that contains an x, in which case your code blows MF-ing up.

Comment: I don't presume to understand exactly what hes trying to handle, however, I attempted to teach him enough about the problem so he can come up with his own solution in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

select replace(replace(replace('mfmfmf','M','X'),'F','M'),'X','F')

Comment: heh, weird how we both chose `x` as the intermediary value and switched `m` with `x`...

Comment: Weird how you both have the same bug, heheh.